# Constructing array of double values from user input

Tags: java, arrays

So i wanted to produce a program in which the user is prompted to input as many Double values as they want, and the program stores these values in an array until the EOF (when the user presses ctl + d), and then prints the sum of these numbers to output. This is what i have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayExample {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter line: ");
  ArrayList<Double> nums = new ArrayList<Double>();
  double input = keyboard.nextDouble();

  while (input.hasNextLine()) {
   input = keyboard.nextDouble();
  }
  System.out.print(nums);
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
   sum+=Integer.parseInt(nums.get(i));
  System.out.println(sum);
  }
 }
}
```

My questions were how would i use a loop to keep reading input doubles until EOF, is the ArrayList the best way to store the users inputs and is that the most correct way to get the sum? Thank you!

Comment: in your loop do... `nums.add(keyboard.nextDouble());`  but get rid of the whole line... `input = keyboard.nextDouble();` and also you might just want to do `keyboard.hasNextDouble();` as your while loop condition... as of right now though your code does not compile because you do.. `while(input.hasNextLine())` Also... no need for the `sum += Integer.parseInt(nums.get(i));` just simply do... `sum += nums.get(i);`

Comment: @3kings It compiles with `hasNextLine()`, it just won't work at runtime.

Comment: @Andreas no... he has... `input.hasNextLine()` that doesn't make any sense... considering `input` is a double

Comment: @3kings You're right, I just thought you were correcting the `hasNextLine()` to `hasNextDouble()`, and didn't notice that you also corrected `input` to `keyboard`.

Comment: Why store the values the user is entering? Your described requirement is for the `sum`, and you can calculate that as the user enters values. And, `Integer.parseInt(nums.get(i))` is not what I would call a best practice.

Comment: @3kings When i run the program now, and the user enters values, for some reason the first value that they enter is not accounted for and the array begins storing only from the 2nd one. This is the code:
System.out.println("Enter data set: ");
  
    ArrayList<Double> nums = new ArrayList<Double>();
  double input = keyboard.nextDouble();

  while (keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {
   nums.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
  }
  System.out.println(nums);
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
   sum+= nums.get(i);
   System.out.println(sum);

Comment: @ShahrokhAryana wells that because of this line... `double input = keyboard.nextDouble();`  instead just delete it since you aren't using it anymore

Comment: @3kings Thank you so much that cleared a lot up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `while` and `for` loops as per the snippet below. In the while loop, just use Scanner's `hasNextDouble()` method directly and add values to your **Arraylist** as they are entered. In the `for` loop, you don't need to parse the values to integers since sum is a double which is the datatype of your Arraylist. Arraylist is right for your case since you are not sure of how many values you will get from the user; Arraylists are resizable.

```
  while (keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {
      nums.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
  }
  keyboard.close();
  System.out.println(nums);
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
   sum += nums.get(i);
  }
  System.out.println(sum);
```