# Passing Strings To array Java Eclipse

Tags: java

I have a java code and it work with success !

```
//data 
double[] query = {0.65,0.78,0.21,0.29,0.58};
```

but now i want user put the strings manual like this :

```
println("insert the values like that {xx,xx,xx,xx,xx} ")
```

i think must use scanner but i don't know how ?

Comment: Have you looked up some tutorials on using the Scanner class? What did you find confusing?

Comment: The official Scanner tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html  You should really talk to your instructor if you don't understand how to use it.

Comment: i dont know how to pass strings from scanner to array

Comment: Your instructor really did not explain this?  It involves a loop construct (for,while) and an index variable.  `i++` is good for the latter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner)

Comment: See also:  "[Constructing array of double values from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660223)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get double numbers from user, use nextDouble() method, like this:

Creating a Scanner object:

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Reading inputted numers from user:

```
Double insertedDouble = scan.nextDouble();
Double insertedDouble2 = scan.nextDouble();
```

Making an array of inputted numers:

```
double[] array = {insertedDouble, insertedDouble2};
```

Answer (score 0):

If input is to be taken in from user input, use scanner this way:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Make sure to intialize array:

```
private double[] array = new double[10];
```

Prompt user for input:

```
System.out.println("Please enter double value: ");
array[0] = scanner.nextDouble(); //gets input from user using scanner, store in first index of array
```

Print:

```
System.out.println(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's straight forward to use scanner try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] arguments) {
         // Set the number of values
         int values = 5;

         // Create an empty array for values
         double query[] = new double[values];

         // Create scanner object to use
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


         // Parse Items for input
         for(int i = 0; i < values; ++i) {
             System.out.println("Please input value num in 0.0 format ");
             query[i] = input.nextDouble();
         }

        // Print the values for success
        for(int i = 0; i < values; ++i)
            System.out.println(query[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to name the class the same name as the file so in this case the file would be called Main.java. I edited it to make it easier. I just attempted the same thing and it worked.